# For collections, when do we prefer using Object type , and when do I use primitive type

Tags: java, generics, collections, types

For example.

```
ArrayList<int> al = new Arraylist<int>();
```

or

```
ArraList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Ingeter>();
```

Also,
I have seen code like this:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
System.out.println("Initial size of al: " + al.size());

// add elements to the array list
al.add("C");
```

Omitting type in `ArrayList` declaration. Is this a good practice?

Should I always declare type explicitly, or this is Java convention to omit things whenever possible?

Comment: ArrayList<int> al = new Arraylist<int>(); is not possible.

Comment: Just as a heads up, you've got a few typos in your first question: `Arraylist<int>();` should be `ArrayList<int>();` (note the capital L), `ArraList` should be `ArrayList, and `Ingeter` should be `Integer`.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I just typed it in my notepad and copied here. Sorry for typo.

Comment: Strange question, you even do not try to run this code and check if it is possible to use primitive types in generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're kinda jumping into the future. :-)

Currently, primitives on collections (and in general, generics over primitive types) are not allowed and the statement `ArrayList<int> al = new Arraylist<int>();` won't compile.

This is one of the reasons why the wrapper types (like `Integer`, `Double` and so on) were introduced. Having them, we're able to store numeric (and `boolean`s wrapped in `Boolean`) values in Collections.

As far as I know, the [**Generics over Primitive Types**](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/218) feature is planned to be introduced with some of the next platform releases (most likely in JDK10, but time will tell if this will be dropped or will be implemented).

Comment: I doubt it, though I can be wrong, since Oracle announced their plans to remove primitives from Java alltogether (Java 10).
Where did you read/hear that this would be introduced?

Comment: Thanks. I got it now.

Comment: @Stultuske, check out the link I provided. I don't know it will happen, but at least they'll discuss it.

Answer (score 3):

It is not good convention to use raw types when dealing with generics.
Also as other poster said, it is not possible to use primitive types as the generic type.

```
ArrayList<int> al = new Arraylist<int>();
```

will not compile. You must use the Integer box class

Answer (score 2):

You should always use type when you are using java 5+

Good

```
ArraList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Ingeter>();
```

Does not compile

```
ArrayList<int> al = new Arraylist<int>();
```

Only for old java versions.

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Before java1.5 you could create ArrayList without generics.. like

```
ArrayList a= new ArrayList();
```

This implies your array list can contain any object. Since the `Object` class is a superclass of all the classes you can insert any `Object` into it.
But it has a drawback.. you have to cast the `Object` back when you use `get()` method.

In Java 1.5 and later you can create and `ArrayList` for specific type.

```
ArrayList<type> obj= new ArrayList<type>();
```

This ensures sure type ensurence and you don't have to cast the object when fetching from the list.

With the collections from Java 1.5
you can store `Object` and sub-classes of `Object`. You cannot store primitives types like `int`.
So in order to store an `int` in an `ArrayList` you have to use the corresponding wrapper class while defining a `ArrayList`.

Java will automatically cast the `int` to `Integer` or `Integer` to `int` with a mechanism called autoboxing/outboxing .